# Listview scroll up when keyboard appear

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating chat app. I want to slide up listview content when keyboard appear or during typing if screen content is full. top list item slides up as like WhatsApp.[image: my app]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCmRH.gif)

[image: WhatsApp pic]

I am using custom toolbar hence when I am using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize", toolbar also slide up.
       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
    static int i=0;
    private boolean switch_layout;
    private ImageButton switch_msg_layout;
    private ArrayList<Message> messages;
    private Toolbar _toolbar;
    private ListView _send_msg_recyclerview;
    private EditText _msg;
    private ImageButton _send;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initialize();
        switch_layout = true;
        switch_msg_layout.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_uncheckbox);
        _toolbar.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
        setSupportActionBar(_toolbar);

        _send.setOnClickListener(this);
        switch_msg_layout.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    private void initialize() {
        messages = new ArrayList<>();
        _toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        _send_msg_recyclerview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.out_msg_recyclerview);
        _msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
        _send = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        switch_msg_layout = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.switch_msg_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.right_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String str = "";
        str = _msg.getText().toString();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btn:

                setData(str, currentDateandTime,switch_layout);
                break;

            case R.id.switch_msg_layout:
                i++;
                if (!(i%2 ==0)){
                    switch_layout = false;
                    switch_msg_layout.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_checkbox);
                }
                else {
                    switch_layout = true;
                    switch_msg_layout.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_uncheckbox);
                }
                break;
        }


    }

    private void setData(String str, String currentTime,boolean switch_layout) {
        messages.add(new Message(str, currentTime,switch_layout));
        _send_msg_recyclerview.setAdapter(new MessageUIAdapter(this, messages));
        _msg.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Activity? android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" should work. you probably do something in the Activity

Answer (score 3):

In your activity tag in the manifest

make this change 
add this attribute

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`

Answer (score 1):

in java class, If it is an Activity, do it in onCreate. If it is a Fragment, do it in onViewCreated.

```
ListView l = getListView();
l.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);
l.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

or In xml, listview add this

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="normal"
```

Comment: will you add some more description to your answeer